# Is there a shortcut to open Command prompt in Administrator mode

Tags: windows-8, command-line, administrator

It is fast and easy to open command prompt on windows: **Win + R** and **cmd**. It is also possible to open the command prompt as an administrator: Right click on the icon and run as administrator.

But this method is more time consuming. So is there a way to do it faster (via a combination of shortcut and typing like I mentioned for command prompt)?

I have tried to use Win + R with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER but with no success:
[image]

Here are examples of command prompts opened with various means:

1. Clicking on an icon
2. Clicking on the icon with right click and run as administrator
3. Win + R, cmd, Enter
4. Win + R, cmd, Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>A</kbd> to open a CMD.exe with admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ctrl+Shift+Enter from the Start Screen Search Results to run a particular program as Admin.

For Windows 8.1 you can right click on the menu entry in Explorer and add it to the Quick Launch. That makes it available from an Alt+*n* shortcut. This may also work on Windows 8.

Comment: Directly running programs as admin is also possible from the Start Menu's quick search function. I believe the combination there is also Ctrl-Shift-Enter, but cannot verify this at the moment.

Comment: @DanielB: I'm 99% sure you're right, but not at a PC to verify.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem, but I was not able to run as administrator with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

Comment: It's definitely working from the quick search field. Just type "cmd", press Ctrl-Shift-Enter – voilà.

Answer (score -2):

press (windows key+x) then release both and press c.

Comment: This only opens a standard command window, not the elevated one the OP asked for.