# How do you launch Windows Terminal from the "WinKey+r" run command in Window 10?

Tags: command-line, windows-terminal

I installed the cool Windows Terminal from the Microsoft Store but I tire of clicking from the Windows Start menu to get to it. It is well known that you may more simply key "WindowsKey+r" and there enter "cmd" to launch and enter a persistent command line terminal. What is the command, however, to launch Windows Terminal, per se, in lieu of the long-time standby "cmd" or even "pwsh"?

Comment: A duplicate of information found in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1560049/1210833), which starts off with that "answer" as the first line of the question itself - *"I use shortcut Win+R to run Windows Terminal [wt]"*.  But also, why would you bother with Win+R when you can just hit "win" and type "term" to find it?  Search for it a few times, and it will probably even become the first thing that is found when you start typing "te" even.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds .. because you then might need to select the icon that showed up by the search.  I just tried this and the result for 'wt.exe' is not highlighted automatically (at least on my machine).  With win+r, I simply hit enter.  No mouse needed.  Windows search (which this uses) is unpredictable.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That's because you searched for *"wt.exe"* (which isn't on the Start Menu), while I recommended searching for *"term"* (which normally results in it finding "Windows Terminal").  Of course, you are correct that a search for "term" even could result in a different result if more than one terminal is installed, but that's the beauty of Windows search - The more you use it, the smarter it becomes, so future invocations find it faster and with fewer characters. But regardless, the "Win+R" "wt" is still a duplicate of information found in the other linked Super User question, IMHO.

Comment: Actually, not.. I type "[WIN-key]" then "WT".  I DO AGREE that regardless, it is a dupe ;)  If you are curious, I have responded to  LPChip below.  Windows search is not smart and it doesn't become better over time.  To test this, I picked the wt.exe SEVERAL TIMES and it didn't change the search order (at least on my box).  No offense though.  We are all just trying to help people and not argue stupid crap. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the convenience of keying WindowsKey+r and "**wt**" or "**wt.exe**" is the solution to averting the de rigueur of the typical 'WindowsKey to Start menu then type and either point-and-click/Enter-Key to select and launch' regimen. Happy computing!

[image]

Comment: You can also just press [win] and after startmenu opened, type wt and once it found wt.exe press [enter].

Comment: @LPChip that is assuming that it is the first hit as returned by windows search.  On my machine, it WAS NOT.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas that's odd.. when I search for wt on my system I get just one result, Windows Terminal.

Comment: @LPChip , That's becuase you have not searched for "OpenVPN HO***WT***O" on your box ;)  That is the first hit when I do this.  Not wt.exe.  I have to be honest, I hate the windows 10 start menu.. started going downhill after windows xp.  We hates it (my precious).

Comment: I do not search the internet using my startmenu anyway nor do I use bing for searching, so indeed, I do not get any internet search results in my start menu. I disabled cortana too.

Comment: @LPChip Hey, that works very well! Nothing in my start menu so far wants to complete with "wt" and it spares an extra "r" keystroke. Can still CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to launch as admin from start menu and life is good. Thank you. I guess maybe the only advantage to WinKey+r is that the Start menu doesn't temporarily splash the entire screen for the brief moment to select-launch, but whatever.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Actually, that really was exactly why I was even hoping for a WinKey+r solution, because keying "Windows Terminal" until autocomplete in start menu wasn't always resolving to the first selection I wanted, i.e., Windows Terminal. But "wt" seems to be consistent on my machine, so far. If that ever breaks, well we have the trusty old tiny not-so-much-in-your-face-as-the-start-menu WinKey+r fallback. haha Thank you.

Comment: @LPChip .. that is the stupid thing.. I DIDN'T SEARCH THE INTERNET FOR IT.. :P  ..  that doc is sitting in a folder on my drive from installing the API.  You and I can disagree that WINDOWS SEARCH IS STUPID.]

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas ah, so you can rename the file to "OpenVPN ALREADYKNOW" and its fixed. :D

Comment: Also, if you use wt a lot, like me, consider pinning it to your task bar. Then you can just click it to open it. ;) You can shift+right-click the pinned item to open it as admin too if its not already open, or you can find the location of wt.exe and set its properties to always launch as admin if you want.